# Any module to update and import data tables to Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have some mysql tables that I need to import to Drupal. The main purpose is to query the tables using a module that I will create by myself, however the data will be updated from time to time. Each table contains the following columns: id, zone, weight and price.

I have checked the [data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module which appears to be perfect to the nature of the data that I am dealing with since I am not actually dealing with content "nodes", however it doesn't provide a built in admin UI that allows the end-user to easily update the data. Any ideas on which module might be suitable to give the users an easy way to deal with such data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module will do periodic imports for you. You can upload a file to it and it will map and import the information.

It is designed to work with specific entities but you can use your custom module to extend it to work with your data.

Then again you are using Drupal. If you want to track "id, zone, weight, price" you can just create a node type to track this and let the feeds module import directly to that node type. You can point other entities to this information through [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).

It is really not logical to track that type of info in your own tables. It's inflexible, you can't output the info through views without additional handlers, and you have to write code to get the data instead of letting Drupal do all the code for you.

You can also import tables using [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush), [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate), and [backup_migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve if you want Drupal to create and maintain the tables within the drupal db you need to look at [schema](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7), otherwise I'm not sure why you need Drupal to import the data as you can write a function within your module to connect to any DB you like and just query whatever you like.